# tuple digits to number conversion

Tags: python, tuples

I am working on python and I'm stuck on this issue.

Input (there is a tuple):

```
a = (0, 1)
```

Output:

```
a = 0.1
```

Comment: Can you show other examples and outputs? Do you really want to convert the parts to strings, concatenate with the dot, and convert to float?

Answer (score 10):

**Single digits and only two elements**

```
>>> a = (0, 1)
>>> a[0] + a[1] * 0.1
0.1
```

**Multiple single digits**

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> a = (0, 1)
>>> sum(n * 10 ** i for i, n in zip(count(0, -1), a))
0.1
>>> a = (0, 1, 5, 3, 2)
>>> sum(n * 10 ** i for i, n in zip(count(0, -1), a))
0.15320000000000003
```

Using `reduce` (for Py 3.0+ you will need: `from functools import reduce`)

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 5, 3, 2)
>>> reduce(lambda acc, x: acc * 0.1 + x, reversed(a))
0.1532
```

Using the `decimal` module

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = (0, 1, 5, 3, 2)
>>> Decimal((0, a, -len(a) + 1))
Decimal('0.1532')
```

**Any two numbers**

```
>>> a = (0, 1)
>>> float('{0}.{1}'.format(*a))
0.1
```

**Any numbers**

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 5, 3, 2)
>>> float('{0}.{1}'.format(a[0], ''.join(str(n) for n in a[1:])))
0.1532
```

There may be some floating point inaccuracies, which you could fix by using `Decimal`s eg.

```
>>> sum(Decimal(n) * Decimal(10) ** Decimal(i) for i, n in zip(count(0, -1), a))
Decimal('0.1532')
```

Comment: The first example can be written more briefly as `float('{0}.{1}'.format(*a))`.

Comment: I did not say it is bad. Actually, it was less cryptic than `*a` :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements of your list `a` are single digit `0-9`, you can use maths:

```
>>> a[0] + a[1] * 0.1
0.10000000000000001
```

or convert to strings, concatenate and convert back to float:

```
>>> float(str(a[0])+'.'+str(a[1]))
0.10000000000000001
```

Comment: the *"easy way"* will also only work with the second value of the tuple being in range 0 to 9

Comment: @pepr +refp - true, possibly a rash assumption on my part, adjusted text.